# Django upload multiple images

Tags: python, django, image, image-uploading, jcrop

I need some help uploading images to my server using Django.
I'm using **Dropzone.js** to upload multiple images and **JCrop** to crop the selected image.

What I need to do is to allow the user to upload their images and show them in the same page to crop each image and then send them all to my server as a list of images. My problem comes when I return the uploaded images to the page, I just want to show the uploaded images in that moment and do not retrieve all images stored in the database. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload images they already being send to server. So you can try to mark *just uploaded* images something like "unconfirmed" in your database and show only them to the user. If user crops and confirmes that images, you can upload cropped images to the server, mark them as "confirmed" and delete the "unconfirmed".

EDIT: If you want to store information about anonymous users, [cookies](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter14.html) and [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/) in django might solve your problems.

Comment: What about if another user (let's call it user2) enter the application? All the images marked as "unconfirmed" and uploaded by the user1 will appear. I don't want that, I want to show only the images uploaded by the current user in that specific moment

Comment: @omaestra why do you think so? "Unconfirmed" is just an additional field in your database, so you select images bound to specific user AND not confirmed.

Comment: The thing is that the user does not have to be logged in to upload the images. For a working example of what I'm trying to do you can go to www.printstud.io

Comment: @omaestra, oh, now I see. I thought by "all images" you meant "all previous images of this user". I edited my answer to meet this requirement.